# React screen not updating after object update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my object perfectly updated but it does not render on screen (filteredData / handleOrder function). I tried using callback but also do not render.

Does anyone know what is the possible solution to render the object on the screen (filteredData)?

Here is the code which the object is updated:

```
setFilteredData(filteredData.sort((a, b) => (
  (sort === 'ASC')
    ? a[column].localeCompare(b[column])
    : b[column].localeCompare(a[column])
)));
```

**Full code:**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import MyContext from '../../context/MyContext';
import './style.css';

function FilterByNumericValues() {
  const {
    filteredData,
    order,
    functions: { setFilteredData, setOrder },
  } = useContext(MyContext);


  function handleOrder(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { column, sort } = order;
    setFilteredData(filteredData.sort((a, b) => (
      (sort === 'ASC')
        ? a[column].localeCompare(b[column])
        : b[column].localeCompare(a[column])
    )));
    console.log(filteredData, 'filtered');
  }

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="order">
        <Form.Check
          data-testid="column-sort-input-asc"
          type="radio"
          label="Ascendent"
          name="orderOption"
          value="ASC"
          onChange={ () => setOrder({ ...order, sort: 'ASC' }) }
        />
        <Form.Check
          data-testid="column-sort-input-desc"
          type="radio"
          label="Descendent"
          name="orderOption"
          value="DESC"
          onChange={ () => setOrder({ ...order, sort: 'DESC' }) }
        />
        <Form.Label>Order By</Form.Label>
        <Form.Select
          data-testid="column-sort"
          name="orderFilter"
          onChange={ ({ target }) => setOrder({ ...order, column: target.value }) }
          value={ order.column }
        >
          {[...columnsIn, ...columnsOut].map(({ name }, index) => (
            <option key={ index } value={ name }>{ name }</option>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>
        <Button
          className="filter__order"
          data-testid="column-sort-button"
          onClick={ (event) => handleOrder(event) }
          type="submit"
          variant="warning"
        >
          Sort
        </Button>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default FilterByNumericValues;
```

Comment: Sort sorts in place.

Comment: @DaveNewton how? I didnt get your idea

Comment: Because it sorts in place it's the same array; it modifies state directly.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are *reference values*, sort() won't change the reference (doesn't create a new array), so React bails out the state update (search the Docs about "bailing out of state update").

You should pass a sorted copy of your original array to setFilteredData():

> `[... originalArray].sort()`

Moreover, since you new state depends on the previous state, you'd better use the syntax:

```
setState((previousState) => {
  // transform previousState
  return newState;
})
```